# Redirectmatch 301 on Mediawiki

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I use Mediawiki script on my wiki site. I use site.com/Page link structure now.

I used these link structures before:
site.com/index.php/Page
site.com/index.php?title=Page

I want to redirect old links to news.

I did it for "/index.php/Page" to "/Page". But i cant do it for "/index.php?title=Page" to "/Page".

Here is my .htaccess file. What is your oppinions?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/(.*) http://viki.gameofthronestr.com/$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php?title=(.*) http://viki.gameofthronestr.com/$1
```

I also tried on 4. line:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php\?title\=(.*) http://viki.gameofthronestr.com/$1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the documentation for [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) we see that it matches against the url after the domain and before the query string. You are making the mistake of not escaping literal dots (`.` matches every character). Furthermore, a question mark means "the previous character 0 or 1 times", so `php?` means either `ph` or `php`.

To redirect urls with query strings you'll need to resort to mod_rewrite. Enable it in your main config file, set `AllowOverride` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)) to at least FileInfo, then restart Apache. Then use the following code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1 [R,L,QSD]
```

Change the `R` flag to `R=301` after everything works as expected.

Comment: That's not work. :( This code redirect "/index.php?title=Page" to "/Page?title=Page" I need redirect to "/Page"

Comment: Errr... oh wow. Exactly one year. Can you elaborate what urls fail?

Comment: I need that code after one year again :)

When i click edit button, edit page must open like that "site.com/index.php?title=PAGENAME&action=edit" on Mediawiki.

But redirect block that and edit page opens like that: "site.com/PAGENAME&action=edit". And it give us blank page error. We can't edit any page because of that :(

Do you have an idea for that problem?

Comment: I've made an edit. It now only redirects if title is the only variable in the query string.

Answer (score 1):

For redirecting based on query string you have to use Rewrite_mod. RedirectMatch does **NOT**  match your regexp against query string.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^title=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$    http://viki.gameofthronestr.com/%1? [L,R=302]
```

**Note:** This is temporary redirect. Replace 302 with 301 to make it permanent redirect.

Comment: That's not work. :( This code redirect "/index.php?title=Page" to "/Page?title=Page" I need redirect to "/Page"

Comment: Hi. I noticed a problem. When i want to create new page on my wiki, wiki gives me that error: "Invalid title." I guess reason is the create a page link is "http://viki.gameofthronestr.com/index.php?title=Page&action=edit&redlink=1" like that. So i disable this code until find a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you mean. Can you explain it more?

Comment: When i use that code it is worked for redirect. But when i want to create new page i can't create because of this code.

Comment: My code only redirects requests based on query string. it doesn't do anything else!

Comment: I noticed that. I just ask you for solution. When i click edit button edit page must open like that "site.com/index.php?title=PAGENAME&action=edit".

But redirect block that and edit page opens like that: "site.com/PAGENAME&action=edit".